# Nuts and bolts list type program

Tags: c++

> "You have just been hired at a local home improvement store to help compute the proper costs of inventory. The current prices are out of date and wrong; you have to figure out which items need to be re-labeled with the correct price.
>   You will be first given a list of item-names and their current price. You will then be given another list of the same item-names but with the correct price. You must then print a list of items that have changed, and by how much. "

This is just a general idea of my program it doesnt have to follow the rules completely :)

Also I know using std namespace is bad I just get lazy some times

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class listWprice {
private:
    friend istream &input(listWprice &list, istream &is);
    friend void MakeRealPrices(listWprice &list, const listWprice &prices);
    friend ostream &output(listWprice &list, ostream &os);

    vector<string> list;
    vector<double> price;
};

void clearInput(istream &is) {
    if (is.eof()) {
        is.clear(); return;
    }
    is.clear();
    is.ignore();
    return;
}

istream &input(listWprice &list, istream &is) {
    string tempItem; double tempPrice;
    is >> tempItem; 
    if (is) {
        list.list.push_back(tempItem);
        is >> tempPrice;
        if (is.fail()) {
            list.price.push_back(0);
            return is;
        }
        list.price.push_back(tempPrice);
    }
    return is;
}

ostream &output(listWprice &list, ostream &os) {
    int cnt = 0;
    for (auto beg = list.list.begin(); beg != list.list.end(); ++beg, ++cnt) {
        cout << *beg << " " << list.price[cnt] << endl;
    }
    return os;
}

    void MakeRealPrices(listWprice &list, const listWprice &prices) {
    listWprice newList;
    int ListCnt = 0, PriceCnt = 0; bool allGood = false;
    for (auto begListL : list.list) {
        PriceCnt = 0;
        for (auto begPriceL : prices.list) {
            if (begListL == begPriceL) {
                if (list.price[ListCnt] != prices.price[PriceCnt]) {
                    list.price[ListCnt] = prices.price[PriceCnt];
                }
                break;
            }
            ++PriceCnt;
        }
        ++ListCnt;
    }
}

int main()
{
    listWprice list, realPrices;
    cout << "List" << endl;
    while (input(list, cin))
        ;
    clearInput(cin);
    cout << "Real list" << endl;
    while (input(realPrices, cin))
        ;
    clearInput(cin);
    MakeRealPrices(list, realPrices);
    output(list, cout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a unclear: example input / output? What does `my program it doesnt have to follow the rules completely` mean? Reviewing Code without a clear idea of its goal is near to impossible. And we like most askers making their best effort, `I just get lazy some times` is not helping you neither.

Comment: I mean that was the project idea but if you look I didnt do some and some were changed around but the actual idea is the same

Comment: Keep in mind that reviewing code takes time.  If cleaning up the code is not worth your time, potential reviewers might decide it's not worth theirs either.

Comment: I know, I was kinda lazy on this one sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, I'd probably organize the data somewhat differently. I'd probably start with something like a `std::map<std::string, std::pair<number, number>>` to store the data. The string contains the item name, the first number the old price and the second the new price (with `number` a typedef to a type appropriate to store a price).

Read in the original prices and insert the name and the price as the first number. Then read the new prices and insert the second number with the correct name. Finally, walk through the map and print out the name and difference between the two prices (if the difference is non-zero).

Comment: Thanks my next chapter talks about these so I going to start using them in these sorta things